# Output from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a slight problem with input and output from my MySQL DB. The problem is in one section of my web page. When I enter a supplier's name in my page through a , it is recorded in MySQL database. But, when I use the same name as input for another form which tracks certain information by this supplier, the other table only records the first word of the supplier's name, for ex:

(Data in the suppliers table): Name: ABC Co. Ltd. 
(Data output after second form submission using this supplier name):Name: ABC

I've attached the schema for the two tables in question.

Unfortunately the whole name is not being recorded in the database. I hope that was clear. Please let me know what i can do. Thanks in advance![image: RTGS Table:This is the second table, ie the one which takes as input only part of the name.]

[image: Supplier Table: This is the first table, the one which forms the input to the rtgs table.]

Following is the code that inputs data to the first table in my post. This form uses the 'select' tag which updates based on DB entries from the second table.

```
<?php
include ('navbar.php');
mysql_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD');
mysql_select_db(rtgs);
?>
<html>
<head>

    <title>
    </title>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <div class="form">

            <form action="ntxn.php" method="post">

            <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Supplier Name:</td>


                            <td>
                                <?php                                    


                                echo "<select name='supplier'>";
                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT supname FROM supplier");
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                                                {
              echo "<option value=" . $row['supname'].">" . $row['supname'] ."</option>";

                                                }

                                echo "</select>";                                       
                                ?>
                            </td>
<td><button><a style="text-decoration:none"href="newsup.php">Add New?</a></button></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td>Bill No. :</td>
                            <td><input type ="text" name="billno"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td>Bill Date : </td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="billdate"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td>Bill Amount : </td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="billamt"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td>NEFT / RTGS No. :</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="rtgs"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="submite" value="Save"/></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

---

This is the code that inputs data to the second table, ie, the data in this table is used as input for the 'select' tag shown above. My problem is that, even though the data in table 2 is complete (ABC Co. Ltd.), data in table 1 takes only ABC as input. Hope that makes my question clear. :)

```
<?php

include ('navbar.php');

mysql_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
mysql_select_db(rtgs);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO supplier VALUES 
        (NULL,'$_POST[supname]','$_POST[add1]','$_POST[add2]','$_POST[tin]',
        '$_POST[ed]','$_POST[ph]','$_POST[email]')");


if(!$result){
    echo "Could not add entry to database" . mysql_error();
}

else
{   
    echo "<center>";
    echo "Supplier added successfully!";
    echo "<center>";
}

echo "<center>";

echo "What would you like to do next?";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "<button><a style='text-decoration:none' href=index.html>Home</a></button>";
echo "<button><a style='text-decoration:none' href=newsup.php>Add another</a>/button>";
echo "<button><a style='text-decoration:none' href=newtxn.php>New TXN</a></button>";

echo "</center>";

?>
```

Comment: Please show table schema and insertion code.

Comment: how do i show the schema here? please let me know. thanks

Comment: This is not just an SQL question.  Notice, for instance, that you post no SQL code.  Are you basically asking people to debug your entire application?  To get that kind of help, you usually need to post all the relevant code, and have some idea of how that application works or should work in case people here have questions.

Comment: Click the little link that says "edit", next to "share" at the bottom of your question.  Then edit your question to include all useful information.

Comment: i've added desc to the images above. If at all it doesnt show, the first table is the one that is causing problems, wherein the name is only partially complete. The second image is the one that acts as input to the first table.

Comment: please provide the MySQL INSERT statements, too. No Javascript going on here, plain old HTML form POST?

Comment: Yes i've kept it very simple. No javascript. Plain html and php

Comment: @vjrngn ok, great. You have the MySQL INSERTs somewhere? And just in case you're working with the POSTed values before you INSERT, the relevant code snippets?

Comment: This could be literally *anything*. Possibly the most vague question I've seen today.

Comment: Understandable that it's vague. Apologies. Will update my question with relevant code.

Comment: Well beside the huge amount of injection you can suffer from your code it doesn't look like you have anything that would cut the company name unless it's bigger than 50 characters is it ? Also you have `$_POST[supname]` but on your HTML you have `name='supplier'` your 2 codes makes no sense to your question.

Comment: Thats because 'supname' is the name of the column in my database. If there was a problem with that there would be no input to my table, would there.

Comment: Also, the name given to the 'input' tag in my html is 'supname'. So no problem with POSTing.. just have to figure out why its being cut short.

Comment: @vjrngn LOL, what I am saying is that if your HTML select element is called `supplier` and you try to receive it as `supname` it will not receive it, your table name has nothing to do with it. `$_POST['supname']` would not be set, either that or the form that uses your second code is not the first code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The option elements are missing double quotes around the value attribute:

```
echo "<option value=" . $row['supname'].">" . $row['supname'] ."</option>";
```

Should be:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row['supname'] . '">' . $row['supname'] . '</option>';
```

Since the supname string is not delimited with quotes, the browser only posts the first word (until the first space, assuming the next word to be an other attribute).